# Wavy vertical line on title page

Tags: titles

I want to put a vertical wavy line with a long, shallow period down the side of a title page.  The following adapts the solution provided by ferahfeza, which works well.  My only additional question would be how to make the line be automatically text height.

```
\documentclass[ebook]{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{times,microtype}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\newcommand\titlepagedecoration{
\pgfdeclaredecoration{complete sines}{initial}
{
    \state{initial}[
        width=+0pt,
        next state=sine,
        persistent precomputation={\pgfmathsetmacro\matchinglength{
            \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength / int(\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/\pgfdecorationsegmentlength)}
            \setlength{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\matchinglength pt}
        }] {}
    \state{sine}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]{
        \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
}
    \state{final}{}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every path/.style={
        decoration={
            complete sines,
            segment length=2cm,
            amplitude=0.5cm
        },
        decorate
    }]
\draw [very thick](0,0) -- (0,15);

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

{\begingroup
\hbox{
\hspace*{0.1\textwidth}
\titlepagedecoration
\hspace*{0.05\textwidth}
\parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{

{\noindent\Huge\bfseries A Collection of \\[0.5\baselineskip] \LaTeX ~Templates}\\[2\baselineskip]
{\large \textit{A predictable tagline}}\\[4\baselineskip]
{\Large \textsc{john smith}}

\vspace{0.5\textheight}
{\noindent The Publisher}\\
}}
\endgroup}

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe this question contains some useful ideas: [Setting a wavy sidebar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95762/579).

Comment: Note that `\usepackage` has to be used before `\begin{documentclasas}`.

Comment: The solution from @ ferahfeza works well with a little tweaking for Memoir, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make the line automatically text height.

Comment: @Jeremy A solution with exact vertical size in a minipage environment to avoid placement problems. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `book` class, following code is a starting point for you. You can control all parameters of wavy in code.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{times,microtype}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{1,.60,0,.40}

\DeclareFixedFont{\titlefont}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{0.5in}

\newcommand\titlepagedecoration{%
\pgfdeclaredecoration{complete sines}{initial}
{
    \state{initial}[
        width=+0pt,
        next state=sine,
        persistent precomputation={\pgfmathsetmacro\matchinglength{
            \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength / int(\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/\pgfdecorationsegmentlength)}
            \setlength{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\matchinglength pt}
        }] {}
    \state{sine}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]{
        \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
}
    \state{final}{}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every path/.style={
        decoration={
            complete sines,
            segment length=1cm,
            amplitude=0.5cm
        },
        decorate
    }]
\draw [thick](0,0) -- (0,12);

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\noindent
\Huge \textbf{Book Title}\par
\epigraph{From  Universe}%
{\textit{Somewhere 2013}\\ \textsc{John Doe}}
%

\titlepagedecoration
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option using a `coil` decoration:

```
\documentclass[ebook]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

{
\begingroup 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\hbox{%
\hspace*{0.25\textwidth}
\parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{%
{\noindent\Huge\bfseries I Want A Poem}\\[1\baselineskip]
{\large A Sequence of Poetry}\\[4\baselineskip]
{\Large Valerie Senyk}
\vspace{0.5\textheight}
\noindent Vocamus Press | Guelph, Ontario}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\draw[overlay,decorate,decoration={coil,aspect=0,segment length=20pt}]
  (current page text area.north west) --
  (current page text area.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\endgroup}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With you're current settings there are some problems with the placement of "Ontario" that you might want to take a look at.

Answer (score 2):

With some caligraphics :

[image]

```
\documentclass[ebook]{memoir}
\usepackage{epigraph,graphicx,calc}
\usepackage{times,microtype}

\newsavebox{\MYbox}%
\newlength\MYh\newlength\MYd%

\newenvironment{Zigoui}[1][ondule.1]{%
    \def\Barre{#1}
    \begin{lrbox}{\MYbox}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth -4bp -.7cm -.3cm }}{%
        \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}%
    \settoheight{\MYh}{\usebox{\MYbox}}%
    \settodepth{\MYd}{\usebox{\MYbox}}%
    \addtolength{\MYh}{\MYd+4bp}%

    \medskip
    \hfill
    \raisebox{\totalheight-3bp}{%
        \includegraphics*[clip=true,bb= 1 -3 \MYh*72.27 3,angle=-90]{\Barre}}
    \hspace{0.3cm}\usebox{\MYbox}%
    \par\addvspace{2ex}
    }%

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{Zigoui}
{%
\noindent\Huge\bfseries A Collection of \\[0.5\baselineskip] \LaTeX ~Templates}\\[2\baselineskip]
{\large \textit{A predictable tagline}}\\[4\baselineskip]
{\Large \textsc{john smith}}

\vspace{0.5\textheight}
{\noindent The Publisher}
\end{Zigoui}
\end{document}
```

And ondule.1 from metapost :
By the way, how to do such a line with tikz ?

```
u := .75mm ;
h := -.9u ;
l := 1.85u ;
nb := 200 ;

path p ;

beginfig(1)

pickup pencircle scaled 1pt yscaled .3 rotated -60 ;

p = (0,h){dir0}..{dir0}(l,-h){dir0}..{dir0}(2l,h)  ;

for i=0 upto nb :
draw p shifted (2i*l,0) ;
endfor ;

clip currentpicture to (.4l,2h)--(nb*2*l,2h)--(nb*2*l,-2h)--(.4l,-2h)--cycle ;
endfig ;
end
```