# What means \p1, \p2 and the nodes P, O, Q, ... in mdframed package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

I want to use `mdframed` package and I was watching some examples from a template by Marion Lachaise & François Févotte from [LaTeX templates](http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com)

But I found this: (in the tikz part)

```latex
\mdfdefinestyle{file}{
    innertopmargin=1.6\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=0.8\baselineskip,
    topline=false, bottomline=false,
    leftline=false, rightline=false,
    leftmargin=2cm,
    rightmargin=2cm,
    singleextra={%
        \draw[fill=black!10!white](P)++(0,-1.2em)rectangle(P-|O);
        \node[anchor=north west]
        at(P-|O){\ttfamily\mdfilename};
        %
        \def\l{3em}
        \draw(O-|P)++(-\l,0)--++(\l,\l)--(P)--(P-|O)--(O)--cycle;
        \draw(O-|P)++(-\l,0)--++(0,\l)--++(\l,0);
    },
    nobreak,
}
```

And I don't know what P and O nodes are. I tried searching on the documentation and here in TeX.SX and I only found out that everyone writes a line like this: (in the tikz part)

```latex
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
```

but I haven't found what P, O, `\p1`, `\p2` are. So can anyone tell me what they are and how to use them?

Comment: Documentation? You sure it isn't mentioned in mdframed documentation? Would be weird if it's the case...

Comment: Also try to include a [example]. Could be something defined in the template somewhere above too

Comment: I tried in the documentation searching `\p1`, but the only times it appears is in the examples and even searched in the .mdf that is loaded when the `framemethod=tikz` is used [md-frame-1.mdf](https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed/blob/master/md-frame-1.mdf)

Comment: No, the p1/p2 is a TeX thing, see manual (4.1.3 the circle around A) P and O I can't find however, but try just drawing their location to see where they are.

Comment: this should clarify your doubt -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/588315/197451

Comment: Thans @jsbibra it was just what I need to know about the coordinates, and also thanks to @user202729 I found all the `\p1` stuff in the TikZ manual.

Comment: Unrelated but I would recommend that you use tcolorbox instead of mdframed.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @UlrikeFischer , can I ask why do you recommend that?

Comment: Well compare the documentation and the dates of the last updates. The difference between both are quite obvious.  Tcolorbox is much more powerful and it actively maintained.

Comment: I hadn't noticed! Thanks for your recommendation, I will read the documentation and pass what I have done to tcolorbox. It seems better as you said.